# Does Electrostatic potential energy bend Space-time?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, mass-energy

Okay, there are various questions.

First, "matter and energy bends space-time" does this mean any form of energy can bend space-time?

Does theory of relativity assume that there is no other form of energy other than mass energy (includes kinetic energy) and light energy?

And is it true? I mean, is every form of energy in basic form is mass energy (includes kinetic energy) or light energy? For example, I think that electrostatic potential energy is virtual potential energy caused due to exchange of bosons, which basically is mass energy.

So, Does electrostatic potential or magnetic potential energy bend space-time? Can field theory and relativity co-exist?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34879/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466993/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, energy is the source of the gravitational field. Any form of energy, including electromagnetic energy, pressure, kinetic energy ,..., and the gravitational field itself is bending spacetime. All these energys (except the energy by the gravitational field) are combined in the Stress-energy tensor. This is why you have a diffrent metric for nonrelativistic objects, rotating objects, charged objects,...
And generall reletivity is a field theory.